# Perl : Handling duplicate element names using XML::SAX

Tags: perl

How to handle duplicate element names in perl XML::SAX module ? Following is my xml file:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>gg</age>
        <department>Operations</department>
        <amount Ccy="EUR">100</amount>
        <company>
            <name> abc </name>
        </company>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Larry</name>
        <age>45</age>
        <department>Accounts</department>
        <amount Ccy="EUR">200</amount>
        <company>
            <name> xyz </name>
        </company>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

My question is how to access the element employees->employee->company->name?  (I should be able to print "abc" and "xyz").The reason I am asking this is because there is one more 'name' element at employees->employee->name which i want to skip. I would like to use XML::SAX only as my environments only supports this module. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stack to keep record of which nodes you're within by `push`ing every time you enter a node, and `pop`ing every time you leave a node:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
use XML::SAX::PurePerl;

my (@nodes, $characters, @names);

my $factory = new XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
my $handler = new XML::SAX::PurePerl;
my $parser = $factory->parser(
                  Handler => $handler,
                  Methods => {
                  start_element => sub {
                      push @nodes, shift->{LocalName};
                  },
                  characters => sub {
                      $characters = shift->{Data};
                  },
                  end_element => sub {
                      if (shift->{LocalName} eq 'name' && $nodes[-2] eq 'company') {
                          push @names, $characters;
                      }
                      pop @nodes;
                  }
              }
              );
$parser->parse_uri("sample2.xml");

print Dumper \@names;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          ' abc ',
          ' xyz '
        ];
```

`$nodes[-2]` is the second to last element in `@nodes` and will resolve to 'employee' or 'company' when `shift->{LocalName}` equals 'name'

Comment: Switching to `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Twig` would reduce the code to about three lines. This is exactly the type of job not suitable for SAX :-)

Comment: @choroba: That's true assuming his xml-file isn't huge, and memory is of concern. In his question he states that it's the only module he has available. There's also limited usage examples of `XML::SAX`, as far as I can tell, so it's worth the effort if only to show that it's best avoided if possible. ;) I love concise code as much as the next (Perl) guy.